# ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'. Use pip or conda to install openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am trying to run the following pandas code to create a df by reading an excel. However I receive the error below. (I pip-installed the openpyxl but I get the same error.)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
           
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")

return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

Comment: Where are you running this code? Make sure your are installing the packages in the correct python interpreter. If your are using jupiter just try !pip install openpyxl (in a cell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jupyter (with anaconda) is using a specific python environment independent from the local python installation in your computer. First make sure your are installing the packages in the correct interpreter if you want to install it into anaconda (jUPYTER NOTEBOOK) try:

```
conda activate
pip install openpyxl
```

otherwise just make sure you don't have diferent versions of python 3 or just install it to the specific version you are using. For example if I'm running the code with python 3.9 I'll run the code below:

```
python3.9 -m pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: for python 3.8 the comend: ```python3.8 -m pip install openpyxl``` it's working, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 17):

```
pip install openpyxl --upgrade
```

If this doesn't work, try this too:

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have `openpyxl` already installed? or it throws error when trying to install it?

Comment: It is installed successfully, but I am receiving the same error.

Comment: Try one more thing, `pip install openpyxl --pre` or `pip install pandas --pre`

Comment: The same. However when I am running the same thing in spyder in anaconda it runs. But in Pycharm in the local machin I am taking this message.

Comment: Pycharm is using an other python interpreter you need to install there the packages too

Answer (score 1):

You can also install the 'openpyxl' package directly in the 'ipynb' file itself using a single command panel:

```
%conda install openpyxl
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that my IDE (Visual Studio Code) was running my code with a different python interpreter to the python interpreter that the openpyxl package was installed in.

I was able to resolve my issue by navigating to "Command Palette" in Visual Studio Code, searching for Python Interpreter, selecting the Python Interpreter that openpyxl was getting installed into, then re-running my code. Once I changed the interpreter it worked for me without issue :)